# How to extract only first url from text with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this regexp

```
function isValidURL(text) {

        var RegExp = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;

        ......

    }
```

And text is: Please use http://google.com or if nothing was found ask your question on http://stackoverflow.com

And i need to extract only first url from text below. (http://google.com)

return as url

Comment: *OFF:* You should better use text `Please use http://google.com or if nothing was found ask your question on http://stackoverflow.com` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
var text = "Please visit http://stackoverflow.com and ask your question, or use http://google.com";

var match = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/​​​​​​​​​​​​.exec(text)​​​​​​​;

​console.log(match[0]);​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/yh5Zv/

Comment: how about when the url is just www.stackoverflow.com (no http:// ...) or even when the url look like stackoverflow.com

Comment: but what if no space like : http://stackoverflow.comhttp://google.com how  get first ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this(provided u don't have :// in ur text other than the url itself) :-

```
var text = "Please visit http://stackoverflow.com and ask your question, or use http://google.com";

var text_split = text.split('://'); 
var text_req = text_split[1].(" "); // splitting with blank space 

var finalURL = "http://" + test_req[0];
```